# String functions in Sybase ASE

Tags: sap-ase

I want to retrieve "name" from "My_name_is_ABC", how to do it in Sybase-ASE ?

I tried finding on internet but inbuild functions i saw are not supported in ase.

Atleast i need to know how to do find index of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sybase ASE does have inbuilt string functions as [Documented Here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks101.htm). You can use `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` function to get your desired result like below

```
select substring("My_name_is_ABC",charindex("_", "My_name_is_ABC")+1,4)
```

Syntax for `Substring` function :  `substring(expression, start, length )`

Answer (score 0):

```
select substr('My_name_is_ABC',locate('My_name_is_ABC','name'),4) from dummy
```